# How to use sudo in Fedora?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, sudo, su

I use to be a fans of Ubuntu, when I want to execute a command as root user, I do this `sudo blah_blah_blah`. But in Fedora 16, it doesn't seem recognize this command. Any clue on this?

Comment: it sounds like you dont have sudo installed. `yum install sudo`

Comment: @huahsin68 What is the actual error you are seeing? This is important because in Fedora the user must be specified in the _'#/etc/sudoers' file

Comment: when I type the command, it shows me the user manual sample usage. It doesn't sound sudo is not install, just that the usage is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell tells you it can't find `sudo` then it's not installed and you will need to install it using `yum install sudo`. If it is installed, then it's likely you are not in the admin group, which you can solve that by doing `adduser <username> admin`. If you don't want to do that, then go ahead and add yourself to `/etc/sudoers`. Be sure to edit it with `visudo`.

**Edit**

When using `visudo` you need to just add the following if you want to be able to run all the commands that `root` runs.

```
sparticvs   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To understand the format it goes a little like this `<username> <machine>=(<allowed-euids>) <commands>` and  **ALL** is a keyword wildcard here.  The *allowed-euids* are not required, but they basically help restrict who you can run as. For instance you can define a group of users like `User_Alias DB = mysql, psql` and then use the command `sparticvs ALL=(DB) /usr/bin/mysql, /usr/bin/psql` which would allow me to run the mysql and psql commands as the service accounts that own them by doing `sudo -u psql /usr/bin/psql`.  Just so I don't completely leave you wondering why there is a machine requirement, you can require that the source of the user that is connected comes from a trusted network. For instance, I have `sudo` rules that only allow `sudo` to be done by someone from a trusted host and all other calls to `sudo` are disallowed.

Comment: you mention `/etc/sudoers`, any clue on doing that?

Comment: I went ahead and clarified further above. Also, for more in-depth information about sudoers file see [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Comment: Great help. Thank you so much on your answer.